# Installing mono developed android app

Tags: android, mono, installation, device

I have developed an android app using mono. After installing the .apk file on my device, the app is terminated with "force close" error.
Are there any additional software that I should install on my device?

Comment: Unless you use Xamarin.Android and follow the documentation, you will see such errors. Simply Mono does not provide you every bits.

Comment: @LexLi So what should I do now?